# Kubernetes api server drop requests from a pod causing dial error

Tags: sockets, kubernetes, coreos

I've upgraded kubernetes to version 1.1.7 and got this error from one of my pod, which was calling the k8s ApiServer frequently to check liveness status of every other pods.

```
Error #01: Get http://[api-server]:8080/api/v1/namespaces/production/pods?labelSelector=app%3Dworkflow-worker-mandrill-hook-handler: dial tcp [api-server]:8080: connect: cannot assign requested address
```

The requests were being sent at the rate of ~80 requests/second. While having that error, I was still able to call that API from my local. Restart the pod solved the issue but the next day, it happened again. It seems that the apiserver was blocking that pod to avoid DOS?

I'm using docker version `Docker version 1.7.1, build 2c2c52b-dirty` and CoreOS v773.0.0

```
Linux ***** 4.1.5-coreos #2 SMP Thu Aug 13 09:18:45 UTC 2015 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
```

Kubernetes api server error log:

```
I0306 07:32:13.087599       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:60033: EOF
I0306 07:32:14.596398       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:57257: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.126962       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:60035: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.136445       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:60054: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.210656       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:45384: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.215155       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:45385: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.253877       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:37527: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.265899       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:57258: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.272564       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:57249: EOF
I0306 07:32:15.282808       1 logs.go:40] http: TLS handshake error from ***:59928: EOF
```

`dmesg` in master node:

```
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:04 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:04 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:04 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:04 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:04 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:15 2016] net_ratelimit: 34 callbacks suppressed
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:15 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:18 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:18 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:18 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:21 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:21 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:21 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
[Sun Mar  6 07:32:29 2016] TCP: too many orphaned sockets
```

Comment: How many pods did you have simultaneously attempting 80 qps? Is it possible that your pod leaks sockets, causing kube-apiserver's system to run out of available sockets?

Note that if you have a non-standard kubernetes setup, you'll need to increase the number of FDs kube-apiserver has (e.g., `ulimit`).

Comment: Also, note that list operations are unfortunately expensive right now, and I expect that at least larger clusters may not be able to handle 80qps of pod lists.

However, you may instead consider making a service or a replication controller-- depending on what you're doing, those objects are likely to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 4 hours of investigating, it turns out that because of my application querying the k8s api server. It is written in Golang and use "gorequest" library to call REST api toward the api server.

The gorequest didn't close the request after sending, even though I closed it explicitly in the code. And it was hard to check the number of open connection because it run inside a Docker container. It was normally enough to check in the host by the command `ls /proc/PID/fd | wc -l` but this time, I had to access inside the container to check. So I tried to use the "http" library instead of gorequest and it solved the problem!